# Почему у меня не работает node.js на http://localhost:5000/ , но работает на http://localhost:3000/

Tags: node.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');



app.get('/user',(req,res)=>{
     res.send('Welcome');
})


 app.listen(5000,()=>{
     console.log('i am working  http://localhost:5000')
 });
```

Comment: Что не значит не работает? Что пишет?

Comment: Не удается получить доступ к сайтуСоединение сброшено.
Попробуйте сделать следующее:

Проверьте подключение к Интернету.

Comment: Сам сервер при этом запускается на 5000 порту?

Comment: Да,но при этом на 3000 когда всё меняю,то всё ок

Comment: Откройте консоль разработчика, возможно там есть какие то ошибки?

Comment: (index):6733 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

Comment: Добавьте скрином что ли... Нужен полный текст ошибки

Comment: я наверху скинул проверьте

Comment: Если у вас такая же ошибка, то просто поменяйте на любой порт, кроме 5000